# p5.js manually call setup and draw

Tags: javascript, html, button, p5.js

I am making an online game with p5.js and I would like to manually call setup, and once setup is called I want draw() to run.

For example, if I click a button:

```
<button id="somebutton" onclick="setup()">CLICK ME!!!</button>
```

Then the canvas will be created and all of the stuff in setup will be run and draw() will run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why do you want to do this?

Processing needs to do a bunch of things related to calling the `setup()` function, so there's almost never a good reason for you to call it manually.

### Using a Variable

If you want to not start your sketch until you click a button, you should do that separately from the `setup()` function. You could keep track of a `boolean` that tells Processing whether to start the sketch, then set that `boolean` when you click the button. Something like this:

```
var started = false;

function setup(){
   createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
   noLoop();
}

function draw(){
   if(started){
      //your code here
   }
}

function start(){
   started = true;
   loop();
}
```

Then in your html, you'd have:

```
<button id="somebutton" onclick="start()">CLICK ME!!!</button>
```

### Using Instance Mode

You could also use [instance mode](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html) to delay the creation of your sketch. Something like this:

```
function startSketch(){
   var sketch = function( p ) {

     var x = 100; 
     var y = 100;

     p.setup = function() {
       p.createCanvas(700, 410);
     };

     p.draw = function() {
       p.background(0);
       p.fill(255);
       p.rect(x,y,50,50);
     };
   };

   var myp5 = new p5(sketch);
}
```

Then in your html, you'd have:

```
<button id="somebutton" onclick="startSketch()">CLICK ME!!!</button>
```

Comment: Ok, I used instance mode... it took a little time to put my code into instance mode, but it worked :)

Comment: now I will have to spend all day to edit the css :D... here is the website if you would like to see my project: https://destroyersio.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @BigBenGamerGuyKSPMC Why do you have to edit the css?

Comment: because otherwise it will look ugly :0

Comment: how do I stop instance mode?

Comment: @BigBenGamerGuyKSPMC What do you mean how do you stop it? Instance mode isn't much different from non-instance mode.

Comment: I mean like delete the canvas and stop draw

Comment: for when the player dies

Comment: @BigBenGamerGuyKSPMC I'm not sure why you would want to delete the canvas. Wouldn't you just want to show a game over screen? But if you want to delete the canvas, just use JavaScript that removes the element from the page. If you have follow-up questions, please post new a new question instead of using comments.

Comment: I think it's redundant to use `noLoop()` *and* a variable. One or the other does the trick.